# How to globally ensure siunitx units are upright using a math font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, siunitx, italic

I am using mtpro2 as the math font in my document (exam class). When I type a quantity using the siunitx package, it displays the unit using italics. I do not want this; instead, I want the units to be upright.

[image: Units are italicized. Undesired.]

Units are italicized. Undesired.

[image: Units are upright. Desired.]

Units are upright. Desired.

Code that results in italic units.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{exam}

% standard document packages
\usepackage[top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in,left=0.36in,right=0.36in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo,mtpcal,mtpfrak,mtphrb]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% chemistry packages
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-rm=\ensuremath,inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\cdot},per-mode=symbol}

% math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}

% exam class settings
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{(\thechoice)}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{18pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{choices}
        \choice \SI{1.5}{\hour}
        \CorrectChoice \SI{2.5}{\hour}
        \choice \SI{3.5}{\hour}
        \choice \SI{4.0}{\hour}
    \end{choices}
\end{document}
```

So far, the only "solution" I can determine is to use `\text` to wrap around the unit. All other attempts have failed, including modifications to `\sisetup`.

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{choices}
        \choice \SI{1.5}{\text{\hour}}
        \CorrectChoice \SI{2.5}{\text{\hour}}
        \choice \SI{3.5}{\text{\hour}}
        \choice \SI{4.0}{\text{\hour}}
    \end{choices}
\end{document}
```

This "solution" is tedious and inelegant as it would require me to go through every inch of my exam and type `\text` in the units. I would like to use mtpro2, but I need the units to be upright.

How can I redefine the unit in the siunitx package to use upright text globally when implementing mtpro2? Can I define the unit (e.g., hour) to be in baskervald while having the value (e.g., 1.5) remain in mtpro2? The siunitx documentation states quantities are defined as including both value and unit, so this makes me think otherwise.

---

### Edit 1

I included another picture here to demonstrate the problem I have when I leave out `\math-rm=\ensuremath`. If I leave this code out, the magnitude of the quantity changes from mtpro2 to baskervald, which is undesired. In this case, it does not matter whether I add `\unit-mode=text` or omit it because the magnitude is in baskervald, not mtpro2.

[image: Magnitude changes; unit upright. Undesirable]

Leaving out `\math-rm=\ensuremath` produces the magnitude in baskervald, not mtpro2. Undesired.

Keeping `\math-rm=\ensuremath` forces siunitx to use mtpro2 as the font from what I can tell. Adding `\unit-mode=text` changes the unit from italics to upright since I am guessing it reverts the font from mtpro2 to baskervald specifically for the unit while ignoring the magnitude. Using `\unit-mode=text` with `\math-rm=\ensuremath` creates the desired output.

[image: Desired outpt.]

Magnitude in mtpro2 and unit upright. Desired output.

---

### Edit 2

It seems several people disagree with using `\math-rm=\ensuremath` in combination with `\unit-mode=text` to create this effect. Is there a more appropriate way to achieve the desired output without `\math-rm` to use mtpro2?

---

### Question

What is the most appropriate way to ensure that the magnitude (e.g., 1.5) of a given quantity is in *any* desired font while the unit (e.g., h) is in *any different* desired font using siunitx? Is it possible to make this distinction without using `\math-rm`?

Comment: Does adding option `mode=text` to `sisetup` render you the desired output?

Comment: what's the intention of `math-rm=\ensuremath` ? the default is `\mathrm` which is an upright font....

Comment: Adding that particular option changes the font of the entire quantity to baskervald. Although it makes the unit upright, the magnitude (e.g., 1.5) is no longer in mtpro2, which is undesired. I want to have the magnitude in mtpro2, so using `math-rm=\ensuremath` creates that desired effect.

Comment: Then `unit-mode=text`?

Comment: Yes, that did it, gusbrs! Thank you so much.

Comment: the `\ensuremath` simply wrong: it specifies to use math italic as the font for things that should be set in roman. that is, it is the cause of the problem that you ask about.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I understand this correctly, `siunitx` will detect the font currently in use and when using `math-rm` it `\ensure(s)math`. So, if I agree with you as to not understanding why this is there, I'm not so sure this is the cause of the problem at hand.

Comment: Oh, I guess you are correct! Removing it does get us units in roman... My "answer" shall be deleted soon.

Comment: I don't have the font, so can't check, but does `math-rm = \mathnormal` work for you?

Comment: @JosephWright Using `math-rm=\mathnormal` produces the magnitude in mtpro2 but the unit is still italicized. According to the mtpro2 documentation, using this particular font does not affect plain text, so there are no upright characters (except Greek letters).

Comment: @TheModernShakespeare OK, so `number-math-rm = \mathnormal`

Comment: @JosephWright I believe that worked! The magnitude of the quantity is in mtpro2, and the unit is upright and in baskervald.

Comment: I'm not sure why in a document in Baskerville the digits should be in Times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select `\mathnormal` in place of `\mathrm` with for example

```
unit-math-rm = \mathnormal
```

This is a documented possibility: some fonts don't have quite the right set up for `\mathrm` to work.

Comment: This option is removed in version 3 of the package. I don't know if `unit-font-command = \mathnormal` is the replacement.