# Conflict between Minion Math font and math-mode siunitx?

Tags: fonts, luatex, siunitx, unicode-math, microtype

**Update 3 07FEB2020:** When I replace Minion Math with Asana Math, it also doesn't compile! Seems like only certain fonts work, so it must be a `siunitx` or `unicode-math` issue...

**Update 2 of 06FEB2020:** It seems that this does compile but only when the `\setmathfont` is changed from Minion Math to e.g., XITS Math (thanks to Ulrike Fischer for inquiring about this), so the issue blocking this may be use of Minion Math even though it's installed system-wide.

**Update 06FEB2020:** Removed specific file path (installed font as admin) and replaced with `Numbers` feature since `SizeFeatures` actually works now *by itself*. The stylistic font features (`Numbers`, `Contextuals`, `Style`, `Ligatures` etc) also work by themselves (and together). But whenever I add a stylistic font feature *and* `SizeFeatures`, the issue occurs. [Output log file in a gist here.](https://gist.github.com/airatin/f0f5df719796d3df230c2f93b012557e)

I use LuaLaTeX and whenever I compile the below (in Sublime) it says it works and no errors pop up, but it <strike>generates a broken</strike> won't generate a pdf file.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{number-math-rm=\ensuremath,unit-text-rm=\rmfamily,detect-none=false}

    \usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
    \defaultfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}}
    \setmathfont[Script=Math]{MinionMath-Regular}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \setmainfont{arnopro-regular}[
    Numbers={Lining, Proportional}, 
    SizeFeatures=
    {
        {Size={0.1-8.5}, Font=*Caption.otf},
        {Size={8.6-11}, Font=*SmText.otf},
        {Size={11.1-14}, Font=*.otf},
        {Size={14.1-21.5}, Font=*Subhead.otf},
        {Size={21.6-},Font=*Display.otf}
    }]

\begin{document}

\[\SI{30}{\m\per\s}\]

\end{document}
```

For some reason, when I take out either the `SizeFeatures` or the `Numbers` part of the above code the document compiles as intended. But the font is split into different files so these endings are necessary for the correct font to be used in different sizes, and I also want to use the different font features available, so I don't want to get rid of either `SizeFeatures` or the stylistic font features (`Numbers`, `Contextuals`, etc) if possible. Why is there a conflict between these `microtype` features and `siunitx`?

Comment: this can not be tested due to the local fonts. Are they need to show the problem?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If there is another example of a typeface that uses different fonts for different sizes and is publicly available (i.e., doesn't need this private path) I'd be more than happy to test it out myself. But from what I can see it's any font that uses `SizeFeatures` that has this issue.

Comment: You should be able to demonstrate this with EB Garamond, but I get no error.

Comment: What does "a broken pdf" mean? And is you tex system up-to-date?

Comment: @Thérèse seems like the issue lies when I have both the `SizeFeatures` *and* a stylistic font feature (`Numbers`, `Contextuals`, etc) enabled. So I don't know if I can replicate this issue with EB Garamond since it doesn't have different SizeFeatures as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Whenever I tried to open the pdf Adobe would pop up an error message saying that "there's something wrong with the file", but that's irrelevant now that I installed the font system-wide and *no* file is generated when I compile the above code without file path specified. It works if I remove either `SizeFeatures` or `Numbers`, but not when both are there (and yes, tex is up to date). I edited the OP, please see above.

Comment: If you use Georg Duffner’s version, not the (odd) version in TeX Live, then `\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Rare,UprightFeatures={SizeFeatures={{Size={9.5-},Font=ebgaramond12regular},{Size={-9.4},Font=ebgaramond08regular}}},ItalicFeatures={Ligatures=Contextual,SizeFeatures={{Size={9.5-},Font=ebgaramond12italic},{Size={-9.4},Font=ebgaramond08italic}}}]`

Comment: The log-file stops in the middle. It looks as if you killed the compilation. Is `\setmathfont[Script=Math]{MinionMath-Regular}` relevant?

Comment: @Thérèse I think I have the TeX Live version sadly, but even with the [Google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/EB+Garamond) version it doesn't have fonts named ebgaramond12regular etc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'd like to use Minion Math as my math font, so yes? Unless I misunderstood what you meant? Also not sure why it'd appear like that but I haven't touched anything when compiling...

Comment: Get EB Garamond with optical sizes at https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/

Comment: You want help to debug this so you should try to create an example that other can compile. I don't have the font, so if it is not relevant for your error you should remove it or replace it with a font available in texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah sorry for the confusion! I just tried it without Minion Math and it compiled successfully, so I guess that is the issue... don't know how I didn't identify this sooner! I wonder why Minion Math (or `\setmathfont`) gives a problem in this case?

Comment: @Thérèse thank you for the link; using these fonts gives issues of fonts not being found etc and I've tried fiddling around with the wording of the font names to no avail. But I think UlrikeFischer successfully identified the possible culprit, that being use of Minion Math so maybe that's it...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It compiles when Minion Math is replaced with XITS Math, so I'm guessing the issue is with Minion Math specifically but unsure why; they're both installed system-wide...

Comment: You should update the MWE and the log file. I have no problems compiling with Asana Math and EB Garamond. Also, is `microtype` really relevant (the `SizeFeatures` are actually provided by `fontspec`)?

Comment: @Robert Thank you but I just managed to solve the issue; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer from another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437130/how-to-globally-ensure-siunitx-units-are-upright-using-a-math-font#comment1096839_437130) I managed to solve this problem just by changing the `sisetup` to the following:

```
\sisetup{number-math-rm=\ensuremath,text-rm=\rmfamily,unit-mode=text}
```

Some fonts aren't set up for the default `\mathrm` to work, and apparently Minion Math (and Asana Math) when used in conjunction with Arno Pro is one of them.